# Heap exercise in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've got this exercise where I've got to remove the minimum element from a Heap and return a tuple with (a,b) where a = the element removed and b = the new Heap.

So where's my code

```
removeMin :: Ord a => Heap a -> (a, Heap a)
removeMin (Node r (Node a b c) (Node x y z)) = (r, newHeap (Node a b c) (Node x y z))
  where
    newHeap Empty Empty = Empty
    newHeap h Empty = h
    newHeap Empty h = h
    newHeap (Node a b c) (Node x y z) = (Node (min a x) (newHeap b c) (newHeap y z))
```

And I get this error code

```
No instance for (Show (Heap a0)) arising from a use of ‘print’
In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

when I try to do something like this

```
 removeMin (Node 2 (Node 5 (Node 7 Empty Empty) (Node 9 Empty Empty)) (Node 10 (Node 13 Empty Empty) (Node 15 Empty Empty)))
```

This might be an easy problem, but I'm in my first year of Computer Science and Haskell is my first real coding experience so I'm sorry to bother with such simples questions, but I really appreciate the help.

Comment: You need to define you `data Heap = ... deriving (Show)`, see http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses. Also, try to not make lines longer than 70 or 80 chars, and before a `where` is always a good place to make a newline.

Comment: @mb21, can you please make this an answer?

Comment: @Olathe data Heap a = Empty | Node a (Heap a) (Heap a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (Heap a) where
    show (Empty) = "Empty"
    show (Node x a b) = ("Node ") ++ show x ++ (" (") ++ show a ++ (") ") ++ ("(") ++ show b ++ (")")

removeMin :: Ord a => Heap a -> (a,Heap a)
removeMin (Node a e d) = (a,build e d) where
    build (Node a e d) (Node b e2 d2)
        | (a < b) = (Node a (build e d) (Node b e2 d2))
        | otherwise = (Node b (Node a e d) (build e2 d2))
    build a Empty = a
    build Empty b = b
```

JBB is your friend

Comment: Hey thanks! And if you're taking the test tomorrow, good luck!